# How to do a cummsum in a lambda call using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to replicate a code in Python using PySpark, and I found myself in a problem. So this is the code I am trying to replicate:

```
df_act = (df_act.assign(n_cycles = (lambda x: (x.cycles_bol != x.cycles_bol.shift(1)).cumsum())))
```

Keep in mind that I am working with a dataframe, and that cycles_bol is a column of dataframe "df_act".
and I simply can't. The closest I think I have gotten to the solution is the following:

```
df_act=df_act.withColumn(
        "grp", 
        when(df_act['cycles_bol'] == lead("cycles_bol").over(Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy("timestamp")),0).otherwise(1).over(Window.orderBy("timestamp"))
    ).drop("grp").show()
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you post your sample input data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You dindt give much information
You have to `orderBy`,use lag to check if `cycles_bol` consecutives are the same and conditionally add. Use an existing column to `orderBy` if it wont change the order of `cycles_bol`. If you dont have such a column, generate one using `monotonically_increasing` function like I did.

```
df_act.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id()).withColumn('n_cycles',sum(when(lag('cycles_bol').over(Window.orderBy('id'))!=col('cycles_bol'),1).otherwise(0)).over(Window.orderBy('id'))).drop('id').show()

+----------+--------+
|cycles_bol|n_cycles|
+----------+--------+
|         A|       0|
|         B|       1|
|         B|       1|
|         A|       2|
|         B|       3|
|         A|       4|
|         A|       4|
|         B|       5|
|         C|       6|
+----------+--------+
```